# Doubling an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to get my array

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

to double. I've made a function with a for loop to print each number twice but for some reason "4" gets printed three times rather than two. I've tried to arr.pop it but nothing happens. Am I putting it in the wrong place or do I have to do something else? My code:

```
function start()
{
    var arr = [1,2,3,4];
    var doubled = doubleList(arr);
    println(doubled);
}

function doubleList(arr)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var cur = arr[i];
        print(cur);
        print(",");
        print(cur);
        print(",");
    }
    return cur;
}
```

And my results:

```
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4
```

Comment: You're using `print`? I didn't know JS had a `print` for that purpose. And are you sure the last 4 isn't the return value of the function?

Comment: Your function already does the printing - no need to do _another_ print after the function `println(doubled);`. That will print the last element again as the last element is what is returned from your function. As a side note, this does not look like valid js.

Comment: Coz u return cur and then print it..

Comment: use: `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)`

Comment: @DBQ That is incorrect.

Comment: To solve problems like these you need to learn how to debug your code. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to do so.

Comment: Note that a function should typically print **or** return a value, but not both.

Comment: Not sure if doubling is the right terminology... its not **duplicate** items inside of an array what you wanna do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the last read character in `doubleList()`, and then printing it in `start()`. Thats why you have last character 3 times instead of 2.

```
function start()
{
    var arr = [1,2,3,4];
    var doubled = doubleList(arr);
    println(doubled); // here is the problem. try removing this
}

function doubleList(arr)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var cur = arr[i];
        print(cur);
        print(",");
        print(cur);
        print(",");
    }
    return cur;
}
```

Comment: Ugh it's always the obvious stuff with me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The last 4 that is printed comes from

```
println(doubled);
```

this is maintained in the same line as the others due to the other print statements being simple `print` and not `println`

Answer (score 3):

My doubleList function would look like this:

```
function doubleList(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
        result.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you should also show how to use it, since OP's doing something a bit different (that is, printing on the run)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Frederico, I'm a newbie here. But as the "start" function would stay the same, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: You wouldn't know if it stays the same, since we don't know the implementation for `println`, that may very well not accept arrays. But, as I said, it's not so important.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I missunderstood the question, here is an elegant ES6 solution.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];

const double2 = arr.reduce( (res, current, index, array) => {
    return res.concat([current, current]);
}, []);

console.log(double2)
```

Comment: `[].concat(...arr.map(el => [el, el]));` is _even more_ elegant :)

Comment: @Andy Yeah.. Im impressed Sir.